TextField arrows up & down didn't work when change Align to center or right in Flutter
When I using **TextField **Widget and using TextAlign.center Or TextAlign.right.
When I press on arrows up & down the **curser **must go to begin or end of text but an error has occurred and the message of error is
======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while processing the key message handler:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart': Failed assertion: line 206 pos 12: 'isValid': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      VerticalCaretMovementRun.movePrevious (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:206:12)
#3      _UpdateTextSelectionVerticallyAction.invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:5557:61)
#4      _OverridableContextAction.invokeDefaultAction (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:1811:28)
#5      _OverridableActionMixin.invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:1676:9)
#6      Action._invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:336:19)
#7      ActionDispatcher.invokeActionIfEnabled (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:666:28)
#8      ShortcutManager.handleKeypress (package:flutter/src/widgets/shortcuts.dart:851:83)
#9      _ShortcutsState._handleOnKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/shortcuts.dart:1042:20)
#10     _HighlightModeManager.handleKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:1837:32)
#11     KeyEventManager._dispatchKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:996:34)
#12     KeyEventManager.handleRawKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:1061:17)
#13     BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:223:49)
#14     _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:567:35)
#15     _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:344:13)
#16     _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:45:5)
#17     _Channel.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:135:31)
#18     ChannelBuffers.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:343:17)
#19     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:722:22)
#20     _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:257:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
KeyMessage: KeyMessage([KeyDownEvent#4fac5(physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#583f3(usbHidUsage: "0x00070052", debugName: "Arrow Up"), logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#88515(keyId: "0x100000304", keyLabel: "Arrow Up", debugName: "Arrow Up"), character: null, timeStamp: 1053:00:12.031630)])
====================================================================================================


Using TextField Widget.
Using TextAlign.center Or TextAlign.right.
Press on arrows up & down.
Expected results
Curser must go to begin or end of text

Can you share minimal issue reproducible code example
